# Using nginx to redirect dynamic request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, druid

I have a druid service which runs at my local machine at port 8082 as follows:

```
Method POST: http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/?pretty
Body:
{
  "queryType" : "topN",
  "dataSource" : "some_source",
  "intervals" : ["2015-09-12/2015-09-13"],
  "granularity" : "all",
  "dimension" : "page",
  "metric" : "edits",
  "threshold" : 25,
   "filter": {
    "type": "and",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "selector",
        "dimension": "pix_id",
        "value": "1234"
      }
  }
}
```

Hitting this query gives me a list of records based on the value of the dimension 'pix_id'.

Now, I want to setup an nginx such that the external application should not have any clue about my druid service. I just want the external application to hit the URL:

```
http://localhost:80/pix_id/98765
```

This url should dynamically generate a JSON with the above mentioned pix_id and send a request to druid and return the response to the user.

Is it possible to do this in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, but rather I would suggest to have a php or python script in between to give the results.

So the setup would be -

1. Have php page receive the request.
2. make a curl call from php to the druid, locally.
3. get the result and pass on the response.

There are multiple benefits of doing this eg. -

1. You completely mask druid, and not necessarily limited to druid.
2. You can do more calculations in php before sending the request to druid.
3. caching at php end.